# Getting an error in macbook M1 while install cocopods

Tags: flutter, dart, apple-m1

I'm using a MacBook M1 chip with a macOS Ventura 13.0, working on the flutter app.

I'm getting this error while I run this command.
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi.
[image]
Can anyone help me, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue:

in regular terminal:

> sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

then in the project root

> cd ios && arch -x86_64 pod install && cd ../

I also had to delete Flipper lines in ios/Podfile to get the app running. (But that's probably not related to your problem)

Comment: I try this, but getting the same error.

Comment: @Jon did you take a look at the `mkmf.log` file output? That helped me identify that the build script was using a different path for the Ruby files than what was in my actual filesystem. Not sure if it's related to your issue but it might be.

Answer (score 0):

I do this when this happens on my M1 and it fixes the issue :

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod repo update

arch -x86_64 pod update

arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: I'm getting the error on run this command
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi